# Using the Archimedean Property in a proof

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I am working through some exercises in an introductory Real Analysis course, and I am having trouble with the following proof.

> Use the Archimedean property to prove that if $a, b \in {\displaystyle \mathbb {R} }$ and if $a \leq b$ + $\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \in {\displaystyle \mathbb {N} }$, then $a \leq b$.

The definition of the Archimedean property is if $x \in {\displaystyle \mathbb {R} }$, then there exists $n_{x} \in {\displaystyle \mathbb {N} }$ such that $x \leq n_{x}$. My goal is to do a proof by contradiction. Here is what I have so far:

Suppose $a \gt b$. If we assume $a \leq b$ + $\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \in {\displaystyle \mathbb {N} }$, then by subtracting $b$ from both sides, we have $a-b \leq \frac{1}{n}$. Derived from the Archimedean property, there is a corollary that states:

> If $t > 0$, there exists $n_{t} \in {\displaystyle \mathbb {N} }$ such that $0 < \frac{1}{n_{t}} < t$

Let $t = a - b$, so this means $0 < \frac{1}{n_{t}} < a - b$. However, this creates a contradiction because earlier, we had $a - b \leq \frac{1}{n}$. Therefore, we can conclude the initial assumption that $a > b$ is false.

I don't think my proof is correct, so I welcome any feedback and criticism to help me improve my proof-writing skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re being too pessimistic: it could be written up more clearly, but that argument is fine. Here’s a compact version of essentially the same argument:

> Suppose that $a\le b+\frac1n$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. If $b<a$, then $a-b>0$, so there is an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $0<\frac1n<a-b$. But then $b+\frac1n<a$, contradicting our initial assumption, so this is impossible, and $a\le b$.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Real analysis is my first proof-based course, so it has been a bit of a challenge for me to get accustomed, and more often than not, I feel like I am doing things incorrectly :-P

Comment: @Aspire: You’re very welcome.